# Vega vulnerability scanner build script

Tags: javascript, linux, security, jenkins

[Link to the build script](http://www.panticz.de/Install-Vega-vulnerability-scanner-under-Ubuntu-Debian)

It asked sudo password. 
I entered it, but after big number of successful log rows final result was like this:

```
"./vega.sh: line 25: /usr/share/applications/vega.desktop: Permission denied".
```

How I can fix this or is there any ready to use js (etc.) vulnerability scanners. 
I mean, tar or rpm file, which can be unpacked and started easy? 
Without GUI. Cheap or free. It is needed for the report generation during Jenkins build.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you do not have the rights to create `/usr/share/applications/vega.desktop` (which is done in your script via the line `cat <<EOF> /usr/share/applications/vega.desktop` (and the ones which follow)).

If you are the administrator of this Linux instance try running the script as

```
sudo ./vega.sh
```

Comment: You mean that you used `sudo` when starting your script? In that case try to do a `sudo touch /usr/share/applications/aaa.txt` to check if you can create any file in that directory. If not there is a problem with how the filesystem is available to you (it looks like a normal fs. isn't it mounted read-only?). You positively do have `sudo` rights, right?